# Why is a new group not active after SSH login via tmux?

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux, user-groups

This is my situation:

- I have added a new group to my user.
- I have verified `/etc/group` is properly set up.
- If I do `su - myuser` the group is shown with `id -a`
- But login-out and login-in again (via `ssh`) does not reload the group: `id -a` **does not** show the new group

It is as the SSH connection was reusing some process with the old group settings.

What could this be?

Additional info:

- I am using `tmux`, but on the client. The server where I am sshing to (and where I am changing the groups), has no `tmux` running.
- It could be that this is related to ssh connection sharing.

Answer (score 2):

> as the `ssh` connection was reusing some process with the old group settings

After you mentioned SSH connection sharing, it's quite obvious this is the culprit. To understand the problem let's see how a process in Linux carries information about its owner.

---

### Spawning new processes

All processes stem from the one with PID 1 (`init` or `upstart` or `systemd`, whatever) that belongs to the user `root`. A process can duplicate itself, see `man 2 fork`; or it can replace its own image with another one, see `man 3 exec`. A common way for program *A* to spawn program *B* is to fork, so there are temporarily two instances of *A*, and then exec to *B* (the new *A* becomes *B*). Now there is *A* (the parent process) and *B* (the child process).

Each process carries information about its owner and group(s), see `man 2 getuid`, `man 2 getgid`, `man 2 getgroups`. When a child process is spawned, it usually inherits this information.

In order to create a process that belongs to a user other than `root`, at some point a privileged process must change its owner. It uses `setuid(2)`, `setgid(2)`, `setgroups(2)` and similar to achieve this. Usually the desired UID is given and groups (including supplementary groups) are derived from it. This is the moment a new group gets active.

After a non-privileged process gets spawned, its children (if any) just inherit the information without querying the OS for the *current* set of groups the user belongs to. At this moment the new group cannot get active. There are exceptions: programs like `su`, `sg` or `sudo` with setuid flag and owned by `root` start as privileged. After they make sure the user is allowed to perform the action, the situation is identical to the already discussed one, where the new group gets active.

So `su - myuser` notices the new group because it changes users behind the scenes. Retrieving the *current* set of groups the user belongs to is a part of this process.

On the other hand `id` shows what it inherited from the shell. This information is old; it's from the time its privileged ancestor manipulated its user ID.

Note `id myuser` would notice the new group. Sole `id` retrieves information associated to itself (with `getgroups(2)` and so) while `id myuser` queries the OS for the *current* information regarding the chosen user.

The conclusion is: your shell (and its children) will notice the new group if it's a descendant of some privileged process, so the transition between `root` and your user occurred after the group was added. (Formal note: transition from `root` to `root` is no different; what matters is the act of setting the ownership anew).

---

### In practice

#### `/dev/tty2` or so (without SSH)

I can log in via a standard text console (`/dev/tty2` or so). The relevant part of the process tree is:

```
systemd───login───bash───pstree
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 these are owned by root
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ these are owned by my user
```

After I add my user to a new group and log in in another tty:

```
systemd─┬─login───bash
        └─login───bash───pstree
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 these are owned by root
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ these are owned by my user
```

Because the second `bash` was spawned from a privileged `login` after I made the change, it will be aware of the new group. In this basic case the "log out and log in again" approach works.

#### GUI (still without SSH)

Consider an example part of the process tree:

```
systemd───plasmashell───konsole───bash
^^^^^^^                                this is owned by root
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ these are owned by my user
```

After adding my user to a new group, a new shell (new tab) in `konsole` won't see the change. Nor will `xterm`, if I spawn it from my KDE Plasma (`plasmashell`). But if I log in via `/dev/tty2`, properly set and export the `DISPLAY` variable, then spawn `xterm` from there, the shell within `xterm` *will* see the change. In both cases `xterm` is displayed on the same KDE desktop, but the first one originates (indirectly) from a privileged process that switched users long ago, before the change; the latter originates (indirectly) from a privileged process that switched users a minute ago, after the change.

#### SSH

In my Debian `sshd` (SSH daemon) forks and forks again, the relevant part of the process tree is like this:

```
systemd───sshd───sshd───sshd───bash
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^               these are owned by root
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^ these are owned by my user
```

After I connect for the second time, without connection sharing:

```
systemd───sshd─┬─sshd───sshd───bash
               └─sshd===sshd───bash───pstree
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                        these are owned by root
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ these are owned by my user
```

Suppose I added my user to a new group in the meantime. The "link" I denoted `===` means some privileged `sshd` spawned a non-privileged one after the change. The latter and its descendants are aware of the new group.

With connection sharing this is different:

```
systemd───sshd───sshd───sshd─┬─bash
                             └─bash───pstree
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                        these are owned by root
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ these are owned by my user
```

In this case the new `bash` got spawned from the *old* `sshd` owned by my user. This `sshd` carries old information about my groups, the new `bash` inherited it.

**I believe the same happens in your case.**

#### `tmux`

The problem is not limited to `sshd`. Take `tmux`. In general case of using `tmux`, after a user logs in, `tmux` can be started directly as a login shell or indirectly from a (non-`tmux`) login shell (manually or like from `.bashrc`; with or without `exec`). The tool connects as a client to `tmux` server owned by the user. If there's no server for this particular user yet, it will be started. It's the server who starts a "final" shell. A process tree may look like this:

```
systemd─┬─login───bash───tmux: client
        └─tmux: server─┬─3*[bash]
                       └─bash───pstree
```

After I add my user to a new group, a new `bash` spawned from `login` does see the group. A *new* `tmux` server and its children would see it. But the *already running* `tmux` server and its children don't; this is true even for a child (shell) spawned after I add my user to the new group.

To be clear: `tmux` client and server have nothing to do with SSH client and server; they both run on the same machine. `tmux` will only matter if it runs where the change was made. You mentioned `tmux` on the SSH's client side only, and the change was made on the SSH's server side; so **in your case `tmux` is irrelevant**.

Suppose I have `tmux` where the change was made. To make new shells inside `tmux` notice the new group, I need to exit (not detach, really exit) everything already running inside `tmux`, so my `tmux` server exits as well, so it can be *spawned anew*. Killing the server should work, but this has obvious disadvantages.

Starting a separate `tmux` server is technically possible. If I don't need to attach to already running session, this is the way to go.  See `-L` and `-S` in `man 1 tmux`. If `tmux` runs automatically after I log in, I may need to circumvent this in order to pass `-L`, e.g.:

```
ssh -t user@host tmux -L foo
```

Comment: That's not my problem. I am using `tmux`, but on the client. The server where I am `ssh`ing to (and where I am changing the groups), has no `tmux` running. It could be that this is related to ssh connection sharing ...

Comment: @dangonfast My answer has been expanded and rebuilt.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will need to go through it in detail.