# SSH tunnel server can't close listen port when client unexpected close

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, tunnel

First I know @TCZ asked this question before: [How to release ports on the SSH server when a reverse ssh tunnel disconnects abruptly/uncleanly?](https://superuser.com/questions/742063/how-to-release-ports-on-the-ssh-server-when-a-reverse-ssh-tunnel-disconnects-abr)

But I think @clement's answer is not quite elegance, because it will influence other users.

When I check:

```
sudo netstat -anp|grep 4000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14751/sshd: xx
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx.xx:4000        183.136.170.162:56097   CLOSE_WAIT  14751/sshd: xx
tcp6       0      0 :::4000                 :::*                    LISTEN      14751/sshd: xx
```

I see server still listen this forward port: 4000. And since client suddenly break, server connect was changed to "CLOSE_WAIT" status.

I tried to use client "close" function to change this status, but still not change. I guess it's because server can't receive signal after ssh tunnel break, but I don't know how to send a FIN signal to an already disconnect socket.

So could anyone tell me how can the client reconnect ssh tunnel in this situation? Hope I explain it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `sshd` that "still listens this forward port: 4000" is a process that has been forked from the `sshd` daemon. This process is responsible for the SSH connection that broke (and its tunnels), not for the entire SSH server.

If you know the SSH client is abruptly gone, you can kill the process (PID 14751 in your example). This will not kill the SSH server. The `sshd` daemon that listens for incoming SSH connections is a different process.

In general you don't need root access to kill this `sshd`, it runs under the user who used it to log in (compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1408087/432690), the "in practice / SSH" part). The user can log in again (without forwarding ports) and kill the stale process. This will release the port 4000. Then they can request port forwarding anew.

---

The [answer you refer to](https://superuser.com/a/742109/432690) can help. You may use `ClientAliveCountMax` and `ClientAliveInterval` to make similar situations resolve themselves automatically in the future.

> The answer is not quite elegance, because it will influence other users.

Use a [conditional block (`Match`) in `sshd_config`](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match) to assign modified parameters to one specific user only.